# Non-microsoft windows update

Tags: windows, updates

I'm looking for some software I've used before but can't remember the name.  Its something like aup.  Its a non-microsoft alternative for doing updates.

Comment: Does it update Microsoft products or third party products? If you're using something other than Windows update to update MS products, I'd be veeery careful

Answer (score 1):

there used to be **[Windizupdate](http://windizupdate.com/)**, a service (long discontinued) allowing users to update the system via Firefox.

then there was [RyanVM's Update Pack](http://www.ryanvm.net/msfn/) and similar bundles, which are no longer offered for legal reasons.

same goes for [AutoPatcher](http://www.autopatcher.com/) (APUP), which was [shut down by MS 2 years ago](http://www.infoworld.com/d/security-central/microsoft-closes-third-party-windows-update-app-981) and then reappeared.

there are still some non-english bundles regularly updated (e.g. from [WinFuture.de](http://winfuture.de/downloads.html)).

othere websites like [softwarepatch.com](http://softwarepatch.com/) offer only crucial security updates, although not bundled.

Answer (score 1):

Well its not discontinued, but the heise.de offline update app should do what you're looking for i think

Its been superceeded by [wsus offline update](http://download.wsusoffline.net/) - same application/scripts. 9.2.1 was the last version that supported XP, and I suspect they will drop support for older OSes as time goes on.

This *downloads* official updates from MS, and installs them in an automated way